# How to hold the overflow menu after I click it？

Tags: java, android, overflow-menu

I have added some checkboxs in my overflow menu. I want my overflow menu to hold rather than disappear once I click the checkbox in the overflow menu. How can I do that? Thanks for help.

This is my **menu xml file**.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
<item android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/notification"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
<item android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/about"
    app:showAsAction="never"></item>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239163/android-checkable-menu-item

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it.

Add following code in your activity where option menu is implemented.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //your checking other stuff
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

        //main part for holding onto the menu
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        item.setActionView(new View(this));
        item.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

By adding the line: `item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);` I am marking the item as it has expandable/collapsible behavior so it will call the `setOnActionExpandListener`.

This line here:  `item.setActionView(new View(this));` is a view when item is in expanded state.It is just a dummy view because we will never let it expand how i am going to explain next.

You see that i am returning false from both the methods of `setOnActionExpandListener` to suppress expansion and collapsing of the item so the view we gave in previous step would never show up and menu would remain open.

Following would be your menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_check"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="Title 1"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="Title 2"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            android:title="Title 3"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

Notice the line `group android:checkableBehavior="all"` is to tell that all items in the group will have checkable behavior so that you don't have to write checkable in each item.

Answer (score 0):

group is a collection of menu items that shares certain traits, for more information [see](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#groups)

```
<group android:id="@+id/group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_check"
        android:title="@string/follow"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"
        android:checkable="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/notification"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"
        android:checkable="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/about_us"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</group>
```

Comment: What exactly this code does ? See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: group is a collection of menu items that shares certain traits, for more information [see](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#groups)

Comment: Add your explaination to answer not in comments .