# How to keep options menu open in titlebar?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu, android-checkbox, android-titlebar

I need to create menu in titlebar, where user can chose many variants at one time. It will be a filter options of content in activity.

So, it should looks like this:

[image]

I can use standard menu items like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/one"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/two"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And it will work perfectly, but after click on any item, menu will close.
I find old question about it: [Android - keep options menu open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220982/android-keep-options-menu-open) . 
May be already there are some variants to resolve it, without create menu by my own?

Or I can use spinner:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_dropdown"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="some title" />
</menu>
```

But Spinner doesn't support multiselect.
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177919/9715339

Comment: @MayurGajra no, it doesn't work for me

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: No, it's works, first time I just forgot to return `false` instead `true` in `onOptionsItemSelected`. Thank you!